# Intel XDK + Phonegap

Tags: cordova, intel-xdk

Would like to ask, is it possible for me to integrate both Intel XDK API and Phonegap API in a single mobile app?
This is because, some of the API is only available in Phonegap and vice versa.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, if I understand the question correctly, I believe you can access both API's in a single app using Intel XDK.

Comment: That is correct you can use both intel.xdk API and Cordova API in a app and build, include both intelxdk.js and cordova.js in your app.

Comment: Do you mean that, I need to download the cordova.js then include it in my app? awesome.. thanks

Comment: no just add the script tags `<script src="cordova.js"></script>`

Answer (score 2):

These hints can be found in index.html when you build a new blank project on XDK:

> NOTE: do not use a directory prefix with intelxdk.js or cordova.js -
>   they are inserted automatically
>       by the build system, emulator and other tools and are assumed to be in the index.html source directory.
>       You will not find these JS files anywhere in your project, they are "phantom" libraries. If you do see
>       copies of these files as part of your project they should be removed to avoid confusing the XDK.
>
> ```
> When building with any of the XDK Cordova build systems (e.g., "Cordova Hybrid App") you can
> omit the "intelxdk.js" and "xhr.js" script files shown below. It does not hurt to keep them, but
> they are not used in that environment, they are only needed for the "legacy" XDK build systems.
> (In the case of the Cordova build system, the Cordova and XDK apis are included as plugins
> and the CORS configuration is specified as a parameter in the build configuration file.)
> ```

so the answer is yes you can use both , also you may notice that some APIs like `Accelerometer` , `Geolocation` , or `Base` API have been deprecated , and it is recommended by intel to use Cordova API instead to use these features.

[image: xdk cordova]

**Note:**

You will not find source files for `intelxdk.js` or `cordova.js` , as you can see they are `Phantom` files , automaticaly inserted in your script , so you shouldnt add any aditional source for both scripts , should you want to remove any of both sources , just delete the corresponding lines found in index.html:

```
<script src="intelxdk.js"></script>         <!-- phantom library, needed for XDK api calls -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>          <!-- phantom library, needed for Cordova api calls -->
```